# Online Interactive Directory

Tags: ms-access, arcgis-platform, sharepoint

I have the following project and I'm figuring out how to best implement it.  I would like the project to be as highly automated as possible.  The suggestion was made that I make and access table, link it to ArcGIS and then share the directory/map created through sharepoint.

Objective: Put together a list of facilities (company owned, company leased, government leased) on a map.

Criteria:

- Develop a system that can be easily updated by non-GIS users.
- Background data can be stored in an easily updated program (such as Microsoft Access) and dynamically linked to the mapping function.
- Data sets should be accessible to various people in the company (via something like sharepoint).
- Mapping function should allow for layers of data

My main question is the use of access and share point the best way of going about the project?

Also lets say I wanted to link my map to an online database (Orcale based) that's protected by a login screen is there any way to do that?

Comment: You might want to break up some of your questions into a separate post to get a better response.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish most of these using [Google Fusion Tables](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232).

- *Put together a list of facilities (company owned, company leased, government leased) on a map.*

Create a Fusion Table which lists those attributes, plus the address or lat/long of each facility

- *Develop a system that can be easily updated by non-GIS users.*

Fusion Tables is a bit like Excel, so with a bit of training your non-GIS users should be able to figure it out

- *Background data can be stored in an easily updated program (such as Microsoft Access) and dynamically linked to the mapping function.*

Fusion Tables has a [map](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2527132?hl=en&topic=2573107&ctx=topic) option built in.

- *Data sets should be accessible to various people in the company (via something like sharepoint).*

Fusion Tables has the ability to share the tables/maps. I'm not sure about the granularity - it may be all-or-nothing.

- *Mapping function should allow for layers of data*

You can use Fusion Tables layers in other APIs. Eg Google Maps API has a [Fusion Table Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer). Another option is to [create a KML](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171215?hl=en) from Fusion Tables.